# Editing settings for individual plugins

Tags: vb.net

I have a vb.net project that loads "plugin" dlls at runtime to crunch some data in slightly different ways and return the results. To do that, all the plugins implement the same interface, so the GUI couldn't care less how the plugin arrives at its final dataset, just so long as all the plugins deliver it back to the GUI in the same way.

I'd like to set up per-plugin options in addition to the main program options. I have an options form that accepts an object of type `System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase` and displays the contents in a `PropertyGrid` control, so it'll show any `My.Settings` object the same way. Question is, how do I pull the `My.Settings` object out from a plugin that's loaded at run-time?

Comment: Got the basic gist working (see below) but if anyone knows how to make those settings persist like the application `My.Settings` does, that'd be super. Maybe it's not possible...but when I reload the plugin DLL, I lose the settings I'd saved when it was previously loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I used the `My.Settings` for each class library to hold the individual settings, and in my plugin interface, specified that each plugin should implement its own `RaiseOptions()` method, which would create a new instance of an options form, push the `My.Settings` object to the form, and then display those settings on the form's `PropertyGrid` control. Since the plugin is doing the calling, it is set to use the correct `My.Settings` object (rather than the `My.Settings` object from the GUI).

It did require adding a few references so that a class library could display a form properly, but IntelliSense was pretty good at pointing out exactly what I needed.